# Is the choice of Scala Akka vs Java Akka just a choice of hooks into the framework?

Tags: java, scala, akka

Do the Scala and Java versions of Akka share the same code for the actual "engine"? I imagine that the difference between them is mainly just hooks into the framework and not large changes in the code base. My interest in this is largely due to performance differences.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the code https://github.com/akka/akka

Comment: @Tyler looks pretty different. Thanks!